# Need to replace a string from a long string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, replaceall

I have a long string

```
Full_str1 = 'ab@xyz.com;cab@xyz.com;c-ab@xyz.com;c.ab@xyz.com;c_ab@xyz.com;';
removable_str2 = 'ab@xyz.com;';
```

I need to have a replaced string which will have 
resultant Final string should look like,

```
cab@xyz.com;c-ab@xyz.com;c.ab@xyz.com;c_ab@xyz.com;
```

I tried with

```
str3 = Full_str1.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' +removable_str2, 'g'),"");
```

but it resulted in

```
cab@xyz.com;c-c.c_ab@xyz.com;
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what is the input and what is the expected output? What exactly you need to remove?

Comment: @CalvinNunes : I want to get rid of removable_str2 only from Full_str1.

Comment: Need to be with regex? And does every word/site is separated by a `;` ?

Comment: Not compulsory with regex, yes every string is seperated by a ;.

Comment: Without regex you can `split` the string by `;` then loop it and remove every value that matches exactly what you want to remove, in the end just `join` the string again. But probably with regex would be less code and less "trouble"

Comment: so do you have any regex suggestion? Yes I also thought of same of splitting and join back.

Comment: Sorry, I don't, regex isn't my strong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a soluce using two separated regex for each case :

- the str to remove is at the start of the string
- the str to remove is inside or at the end of the string

**PS** :
I couldn't perform it in one regex, because it would remove an extra `;` in case of matching the string to remove inside of the global string.

```js
const originalStr = 'ab@xyz.com;cab@xyz.com;c-ab@xyz.com;c.ab@xyz.com;ab@xyz.com;c_ab@xyz.com;';
const toRemove = 'ab@xyz.com;';

const epuredStr = originalStr
                      .replace(new RegExp(`^${toRemove}`, 'g'), '')
                      .replace(new RegExp(`;${toRemove}`, 'g'), ';');

console.log(epuredStr);
```

Comment: There is no need for two `replace` operations, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59684320/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

First, the dynamic part must be [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/3832970), else, `.` will match any char but a line break char, and will match `ab@xyz§com;`, too.

Next, you need to match this only at the start of the string or after `;`. So, you may use

```js
var Full_str1 = 'ab@xyz.com;cab@xyz.com;c-ab@xyz.com;c.ab@xyz.com;c_ab@xyz.com;';
var removable_str2 = 'ab@xyz.com;';
var rx = new RegExp("(^|;)" + removable_str2.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "g");
console.log(Full_str1.replace(rx, "$1"));
// => cab@xyz.com;c-ab@xyz.com;c.ab@xyz.com;c_ab@xyz.com;
```

Replace `"g"` with `"gi"` for case insensitive matching.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3AATA4/1). Note that `(^|;)` matches and *captures into Group 1* start of string location (empty string) or `;` and `$1` in the replacement pattern restores this char in the result.

**NOTE**: If the pattern is known beforehand and you only want to handle `ab@xyz.com;` pattern, use a regex literal without escaping, `Full_str1.replace(/(^|;)ab@xyz\.com;/g, "$1")`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't find any particular description why you haven't tried like this it will give you desired result `cab@xyz.com;c-ab@xyz.com;c.ab@xyz.com;c_ab@xyz.com;`

```js
const full_str1 = 'ab@xyz.com;cab@xyz.com;c-ab@xyz.com;c.ab@xyz.com;c_ab@xyz.com;';
const removable_str2 = 'ab@xyz.com;';

const result= full_str1.replace(removable_str2 , "");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The text `tatatab@xyz.com;` would be affected by your regex

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT got it